# A new job in Travis-CI cannot get curl library

Tags: ubuntu, travis-ci, apt-get

I have configured Travis-CI with many apt-get, and it worked perfect. But since this week, the apt-get fails and some libraries cannot be retrieved. I have not changed the code. How can I solve this problem:

The library in question is curl.

- Working job (4 days ago): https://travis-ci.org/angoca/db2unit/jobs/47121134
- Current job failing: https://travis-ci.org/angoca/db2unit/jobs/47634811

The error I am facing is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install aria2 curl -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libgeos-3.2.2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc-ares2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aria2 libc-ares2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  curl
1 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 125 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,949 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,179 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libc-ares2 amd64 1.7.5-1 [36.6 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe aria2 amd64 1.13.0-1 [1,775 kB]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main curl amd64 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.11
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main curl amd64 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.11
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::14 80]
Fetched 1,811 kB in 0s (6,802 kB/s)
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.22.0-3ubuntu4.11_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::14 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0):

The Travis [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Linux%3A-apt-fails-to-install-package-with-404-error) lists a common cause of that error as being an old package database. The solution would be to add:

```
before_install:
    -sudo apt-get update
```

to your `.travis.yml` file.

Cheers,