# Error: Required package curl not found. Please run: install.packages('curl') Execution halted on Travis CI

Tags: r, ubuntu, travis-ci, devops, cran

An R package works fine (and passes CRAN checks), but when Travis CI runs unit tests it errors with

```
Error: Required package curl not found. Please run: install.packages('curl')
Execution halted
```

This seems to be an issue particular to Ubuntu. I can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115972/configuration-failed-because-libcurl-was-not-found) that running `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` can fix the issue. The trouble is I don't have access to the Ubuntu console (as Travis CI does everything after I push to git) - can I place this code somewhere? E.g. can it go in `.travis.yml` somehow, and if so, how?

The current `.travis.yml` file is just 2 lines and looks like this

```
language: R
cache: packages
```

#### Note

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115972/configuration-failed-because-libcurl-was-not-found) question/answer, I tried adjusting `.travis.yml` to

```
language: R
cache: packages
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

I can see from the build logs that `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` ran, but the build errored in the same way as before regardless

#### Also note

I also tried

```
language: R
cache: packages
before_install:
    -sudo apt-get update
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046457/a-new-job-in-travis-ci-cannot-get-curl-library) suggestion, but the same error persisted

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away by adding `curl` to imports (i.e. in `DESCRIPTION`)

e.g.

`Imports: dplyr, gsubfn, stringr, purrr, jsonlite, stats, lubridate, curl`

If you have a helper file in `testthat`, don't forget to load the package there too i.e. simply `library(curl)`. Then the tests should be able to run as expected